# How to put values in a row in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In QGis when i double click in a field in the attribute table, the column look likes 1, 10, 100, 1027, 11, 110 etc. How to do the column look likes 1, 2, 3, 4 etc

Answer (score 3):

Your field is likely a string, not a numeric type, and therefore the sort is done character by character (so 10 is before 2).

To overcome this, you can change your column type to an integer, or you can do the conversion on the fly when sorting the data.

To do so, right click the column of interest and select `sort`. Then you can apply the function `to_int` to convert the text to a number, and sort is as a number (so 10 is after 2)

[image]

[image]